# write video in OpenCV FOURCC codec

Tags: c++, opencv, video, ffmpeg, fourcc

I am trying to save the results of `YOLO` to `.avi` file. Having already seen [**this post**](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/i)... (I even asked the question there) I could NOT find any solution. Here is the code in which I am trying to save the `.avi`.

```
{
    CvSize size;
    size.width = disp->width;
    size.height = disp->height;

    static CvVideoWriter* output_video = NULL;    // cv::VideoWriter output_video;
    if (output_video == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n SRC output_video = %p \n", output_video);
        const char* output_name = "test_dnn_out.avi";
        output_video = cvCreateVideoWriter(output_name, CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X'), 25, size, 1);
        printf("\n cvCreateVideoWriter, DST output_video = %p  \n", output_video);
    }
    cvWriteFrame(output_video, disp);
}
```

Trying plenty of codecs ( changing `CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X')` ) I get errors below:

```
**CODEC :-1**

**ERROR**

SRC output_video = (nil)  OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0xffffffff/'����' is not
found (format 'avi / AVI (Audio Video Interleaved)')' OpenCV Error:
Unsupported format or combination of formats (Gstreamer Opencv backend
does not support this codec.) in CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file
/home/akde/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line
1522 VIDEOIO(cvCreateVideoWriter_GStreamer (filename, fourcc, fps,
frameSize, is_color)): raised OpenCV exception:

/home/akde/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1522:
error: (-210) Gstreamer Opencv backend does not support this codec. in
function CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open


**CODEC: CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')**

**ERROR**

SRC output_video = (nil)  OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer:
cannot put pipeline to play ) in CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file
/home/akde/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line
1690 VIDEOIO(cvCreateVideoWriter_GStreamer (filename, fourcc, fps,
frameSize, is_color)): raised OpenCV exception:

/home/akde/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1690:
error: (-2) GStreamer: cannot put pipeline to play  in function
CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open


**CODEC: CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1')** SRC output_video = (nil) 

**ERROR**

** (Demo:6801): CRITICAL **: gst_ffmpeg_cfg_set_property: assertion 'qdata- 
size == sizeof (gint64)' failed OpenCV Error: Unspecified
error (GStreamer: cannot put pipeline to play ) in
CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file
/home/akde/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line
1690 VIDEOIO(cvCreateVideoWriter_GStreamer (filename, fourcc, fps,
frameSize, is_color)): raised OpenCV exception:

/home/akde/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1690:
error: (-2) GStreamer: cannot put pipeline to play  in function
CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open



**CODEC:CV_FOURCC('M', 'P', '4', '2')**

**ERROR**

SRC output_video = (nil) 

** (Demo:7437): CRITICAL **: gst_ffmpeg_cfg_set_property: assertion 'qdata- 
size == sizeof (gint64)' failed OpenCV Error: Unspecified
error (GStreamer: cannot put pipeline to play ) in
CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file
/home/akde/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line
1690 VIDEOIO(cvCreateVideoWriter_GStreamer (filename, fourcc, fps,
frameSize, is_color)): raised OpenCV exception:

/home/akde/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1690:
error: (-2) GStreamer: cannot put pipeline to play  in function
CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open


**CODEC::CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', '3')**

**ERROR** 

SRC output_video = (nil)  OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer:
cannot put pipeline to play ) in CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file
/home/akde/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line
1690 VIDEOIO(cvCreateVideoWriter_GStreamer (filename, fourcc, fps,
frameSize, is_color)): raised OpenCV exception:

/home/akde/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1690:
error: (-2) GStreamer: cannot put pipeline to play  in function
CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open


**CODEC:CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X')**

**ERROR** 

SRC output_video = (nil)  OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer:
cannot put pipeline to play ) in CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file
/home/akde/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line
1690 VIDEOIO(cvCreateVideoWriter_GStreamer (filename, fourcc, fps,
frameSize, is_color)): raised OpenCV exception:

/home/akde/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1690:
error: (-2) GStreamer: cannot put pipeline to play  in function
CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open



**CODEC:CV_FOURCC('U', '2', '6', '3')**

**ERROR** 

OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: cannot put pipeline to
play ) in CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file
/home/akde/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line
1690 VIDEOIO(cvCreateVideoWriter_GStreamer (filename, fourcc, fps,
frameSize, is_color)): raised OpenCV exception:

/home/akde/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1690:
error: (-2) GStreamer: cannot put pipeline to play  in function
CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open


cvCreateVideoWriter, DST output_video = (nil)  

SRC output_video = (nil)  Could not open codec 'h263': Unspecified
error

** (Demo:8342): CRITICAL **: gst_ffmpeg_cfg_set_property: assertion 'qdata- 
size == sizeof (gint64)' failed



**CODEC:CV_FOURCC('I', '2', '6', '3')**

**ERROR** 

SRC output_video = (nil)  Could not find encoder for codec id 21:
Encoder not found OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: cannot
link elements ) in CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file
/home/akde/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line
1626 VIDEOIO(cvCreateVideoWriter_GStreamer (filename, fourcc, fps,
frameSize, is_color)): raised OpenCV exception:

/home/akde/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1626:
error: (-2) GStreamer: cannot link elements  in function
CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open


cvCreateVideoWriter, DST output_video = (nil)  


**CODEC:CV_FOURCC('F', 'L', 'V', '1')**

**ERROR** 

SRC output_video = (nil)  OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer:
cannot link elements ) in CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file
/home/akde/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line
1626 VIDEOIO(cvCreateVideoWriter_GStreamer (filename, fourcc, fps,
frameSize, is_color)): raised OpenCV exception:

/home/akde/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1626:
error: (-2) GStreamer: cannot link elements  in function
CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open


cvCreateVideoWriter, DST output_video = (nil)


**CODEC:CV_FOURCC('i','Y', 'U', 'V')**

**ERROR** 

SRC output_video = (nil)  OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x56555969/'iYUV' is not
supported with codec id 14 and format 'avi / AVI (Audio Video
Interleaved)' OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of
formats (Gstreamer Opencv backend does not support this codec.) in
CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file
/home/akde/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line
1522 VIDEOIO(cvCreateVideoWriter_GStreamer (filename, fourcc, fps,
frameSize, is_color)): raised OpenCV exception:

/home/akde/opencv-3.3.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1522:
error: (-210) Gstreamer Opencv backend does not support this codec. in
function CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open
```

**Here is my setup**

-`ubuntu 16.04`

-`opencv 3.3.0`

-`ffmpeg version 2.8.14`

In my opinion, the problem is very likely to be about codecs. Because people solved the same problem by using different codecs. Even though I tried many codecs and have `ffmepeg` installed correctly I could NOT find any solution. So what should I do? Looking forward to your replies...

Comment: Your OpenCV is not built with FFmpeg support. Check value of FFmpeg in the output of `cv2.getBuildInformation()`.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using ffmpeg to create the video, you should first check, as @zindarod points out, if OpenCV was built with ffmpeg. For that, you can run the following code in C++:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(void)
{
  std::cout << cv::getBuildInformation() << std::endl;
}
```

One other thing DO NOT USE C API unless it is necessary. It is deprecated and should not be used, specially if your code is in C++ as the tag of your question suggest.

In the C++ API you can actually select a different backend. Take a look to the [documentation of VideoWriter](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#af52d129e2430c0287654e7d24e3bbcdc).

> **cv::VideoWriter::VideoWriter**  (   const String &  filename, int
>     apiPreference, int  fourcc, double  fps, Size   frameSize, bool
>     isColor = true  )
>
> This is an overloaded member function, provided for convenience. It
>   differs from the above function only in what argument(s) it accepts.
>   The apiPreference parameter allows to specify API backends to use. Can
>   be used to enforce a specific reader implementation if multiple are
>   available: e.g. cv::CAP_FFMPEG or cv::CAP_GSTREAMER.

This mean, if both are installed and OpenCV was built with the support from both you can switch it to your liking :)

GStreamer is not a bad backend to use, I actually use it, but I use it more to open videos rather than creating ones, but you need to have the plugins installed to make it work with more codecs... The [gstreamer webpage](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html) recommends to install it like this:

```
apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools
```

The 1.0 may change depending on the version you are using already.

I hope this solves your problem, if not just leave a comment.

Comment: when I try to execute the code you have written in vs code I get the following error:  /tmp/ccMqUUra.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:647: undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
/tmp/ccMqUUra.o: In function `cv::String::operator=(cv::String const&)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:655: undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1         Trying to fix that now. If you have any comment you are more than welcome.

Comment: @burakakdemir looks like a linking problem, make sure you are linking opencv libraries (or opencv_world if you have it compiled). This one should opencv_core if I remember correctly

Comment: I just run the code you have given using following:  g++ -std=c++11 Hello.cpp `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` -o HelloWorld
and here is the related part of the outcome: **FFMPEG: YES | avcodec: YES (ver 56.60.100) | avformat: YES (ver 56.40.101) | avutil: YES (ver 54.31.100) | swscale: YES (ver 3.1.101) | avresample: YES (ver 2.1.0) | GStreamer: | base: YES (ver 1.8.3) | video: YES (ver 1.8.3) | app: YES (ver 1.8.3) | riff: YES (ver 1.8.3) | pbutils: YES (ver 1.8.3)** so does this mean gstreamer is OK? PS: I have already installed the gstreamer with the command you have given

Comment: @burakakdemir Basically it tells you that you can use FFMPEG or GStreamer. If you installed the plugins, does the code from your question gives the same errors? stiil, I will suggest to avoid the C interface, and use the C++ one, in which you can select either GStreamer or FFMPEG

Comment: thx a lot for the reply. How can i check if the plugins are installed or not. About the c interface, i am trying to implement the method which is suggested in darknet forums & git bcs i  do not have a solid background in linux.

Comment: thx for the reply. How can i verify that the plugins are functional? And about the c interface, as you can see i do not have a solid background in linux so i want to stay close what ppl in darknet forums&amp;git doing. Majority of the ppl there did the thing mentioned in the post. Thats why i am trying to avoid sth different.

Comment: @burakakdemir you can check what package is installed with `dpkg --list 'package-name'`. For gstreamer you can do `dpkg --list 'gstreamer*'` at the begining you will have  `ii` for packages install so you can do `dpkg --list 'gstreamer*' | grep ii` to see only the packages of gstreamer that are installed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176850/discussion-between-burak-akdemir-and-api55).

Comment: adding sudo before the terminal expression & changing the file permissions solved my problem. As you suggested the folder that i am trying to write into was protected. Thx a lot!